# SSAS Orderby for custom buckets on Dimension

Tags: ssas, olap-cube, bucket

i got a Cube Dimension containing:

```
fooBucket
fooValue
```

fooBucket is already evaluated with SQL, so an example could be

```
fooBucket = 50-99
fooValue =  76
```

I then made a hierarchy   fooBucket -> foo and everything works just fine.

The Problem now is, that the Buckets are ordered lexicographic that means i have the followng order:

```
0-49
100-149
150-199
50-99
..
```

and so on. How can i possibly change the order of that DimensionAttribute "bucket" when i cannot just say order by int because clearly it is no int... :(

Answer (score 3):

Just add another column, maybe named "fooOrder", to your table or view that the dimension is based on. This column should be an integer (possibly just the number before the hyphen of the range).

Then add that as attribute to your dimension, and define a relationship from fooBucket to it. Set the "OrderByAttribute" property of fooBucket to "fooOrder" and the "OrderBy" property to "AttributeKey". Finally, set the "AttributeHieararchyEnabled" property od "fooOrder" to false.